# array sort by date

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have the following string which I am trying to explode and sort from earliest date to latest date:

```
$dates = 2010-11-05,2010-11-05,2010-11-06,2010-11-06,2010-11-07,2010-11-07,2010-11-08
```

I've obviously tried `sort(explode(',', $dates));` as well as usort, setting different sort flags, but this isn't giving me any luck. Which array sorting function am I looking for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php

$dates = '2010-11-05,2010-11-05,2010-11-06,2010-11-06,2010-11-07,2010-11-07,2010-11-08';

$array = explode(',', $dates);
sort($array);

print_r($array);
```

If you look carefully at the manual page for [sort()](http://php.net/sort) you'll see that it receives its argument by reference:

```
bool sort ( array &$array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR ] )
```

If you don't feed it with a variable, the results of the sorting will be lost since they can't be stored anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
$dates = "2010-11-05,2010-11-05,2010-11-06,2010-11-06,2010-11-08,2010-11-06,2010-11-08";
$da = explode(',',$dates);
sort($da);
var_dump($da);
```